Improving NCC Template Matching Accuracy in HALCON
I've been working with NCC template matching in HALCON and am facing challenges with accurately locating my template in the search image. Despite trying various preprocessing techniques and utilizing Regions of Interest (ROIs), I consistently encounter issues with precision and sometimes fail to detect the template entirely. I've attached images of both the template and the search image below.
Search Image: 
Template Image:
gen_rectangle1 (ROI, 651.344, 888.522, 730.939, 931.704)
reduce_domain(image, ROI, templimage)

Result Image:

impath := '/path/to/search_image.bmp'

read_image(image, impath)
rgb1_to_gray(image, image)
gen_rectangle1 (ROI, 545.35, 739.29, 612.312, 776.902)
reduce_domain(image, ROI, templimage)

* create model
create_ncc_model (templimage, 'auto', rad(0), rad(359), 'auto', 'use_polarity', NCCModelID)

* find model
find_ncc_model(image, NCCModelID, rad(0), rad(359), 0.68, 0, 0.8, 'true', 0, Row, Column, Angle, Score)
dev_clear_window()
dev_display(image)
dev_display_ncc_matching_results(NCCModelID, 'red', Row, Column, Angle, 0)

Could anyone suggest strategies to enhance the accuracy and reliability of the NCC template matching in this context? Are there specific preprocessing methods or settings in HALCON that could help in consistently identifying the template correctly?
Thank you for any insights or advice!

Why does it have to be ncc recognition?

@VladimirPerković   I have already implemented HALCON's NCC match algorithm using OpenCV. Currently, I am using a trial version of HALCON, but in practical applications, I use the NCC match algorithm based on OpenCV. Therefore, I need to ensure that this requirement is correctly fulfilled using HALCON's operators.

I think shape-based matching would give you better results, but if you have to use NCC this is result I have so far:

dev_update_off ()

read_image (Image, 'C:/Users/Perkovic/Desktop/Jff7mFg2.png')
rgb1_to_gray (Image, Image)

L1 := 41
L2 := 25
gen_rectangle2 (ROI, 691.4061, 911.5726, rad(-88.09105), L1, L2)
reduce_domain(Image, ROI, templimage)
gen_rectangle2 (ROI_0, 718.03, 909.1579, rad(90), 13.33325, 21.16724)
gen_rectangle2 (TMP_Region, 680.0816, 909.1579, rad(90.66528), 29.40351, 13.56099)
union2 (ROI_0, TMP_Region, ROI_0)

** Reduce domain
threshold (Image, Region, 0, 80)
fill_up (Region, RegionFillUp)
connection (RegionFillUp, ConnectedRegions)
select_shape (ConnectedRegions, SelectedRegions, 'area', 'and', 150, 10e3)
dilation_circle (SelectedRegions, RegionDilation, 70.5)
union1 (RegionDilation, RegionUnion)
reduce_domain (Image, RegionUnion, ImageReduced)

* create model
create_ncc_model (templimage, 'auto', -0.39, 6.29, 'auto', 'use_polarity', NCCModelID)

* find model
dev_clear_window()
dev_display(Image)
while (true)
    find_ncc_model(ImageReduced, NCCModelID, -0.39, 6.29, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 'true', 0, Row, Column, Angle, Score)
    
    if (Score == [])
        break
    endif
    dev_display_ncc_matching_results(NCCModelID, 'red', Row, Column, Angle, 0)
    
    dev_disp_text (Score, 'image', Row, Column, 'black', [], [])
    
    ** Remove rectangle from reduced image
    gen_rectangle2 (Rectangle, Row, Column, Angle, L2, L1)
    get_domain (ImageReduced, Domain)
    difference (Domain, Rectangle, RegionDifference)
    reduce_domain (ImageReduced, RegionDifference, ImageReduced)
endwhile


Hi Vladimir Perković,
Thank you so much for your detailed response! I implemented the changes you suggested, particularly focusing on the modified regions.
Your approach, especially the adaptive use of reducing the image domain iteratively, was key to enhancing the matching performance and accuracy.
This not only solved the issues I was facing but also provided a robust way to handle variations in the template detection.
Thanks again for sharing your expertise.

May I ask one more question? I applied a median filter to both the template image and the search image, but Halcon cannot find any matches. Why is this happening?
